# How do I model all the different states of a widget for testing?

Tags: design-patterns, testing, acceptance-testing, puzzles

Say I am a QA person so I have no control over the complexity of the code in the following example.

I have a [datatable](https://datatables.net/) widget with many different filtering and searching options. All the columns on my data table are also sortable.

There are many issues with components not working together. For example, if someone uses *Filter A* & *Filter B* together, it will break. Or, if someone uses *Filter A* and sorts by *Column A*, it will break.

One more example. If I have 3 columns, I want to test with column 1 active, column 1 & 2 active, column 1,2, & 3 active, column 2 & 3 active and so on.

How do I determine all of the possible states of the widget? If I have 5 columns and 6 filters, and the user can sort by as many columns and filters they want, how do I generate a list of the combinations I need to test?

Comment: Are you looking for how to calculate combinations and/or permutations? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination vs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation for instance? If you can have as many filters by as many columns as wanted, you'll end up with the inclusion of a factorial, so the amount of possible states will be "very large" - probably so that you'll need to set limits on what states are tested as it is infeasible to test them all.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a combinatorial problem:

1. You have 3 columns, so you need all combinations of 3 columns: `[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]` where `[` and `]` enclose a list of included columns. And yes, `[]` is a valid combination.
2. You have 2 filters available for each column, plus an unfiltered state. You also have ensure that you have data that represents at least two values for each of the filtered and unfiltered settings.
3. You have 4 sorted states for each column: never sorted, previously sorted, sorted up, sorted down. This combination will be used to test for stable sorting processes.

How do you generate all of these tests? I would be tempted to generate the combinations using a language that handles combinatorics readily. I would be tempted to use Haskell for this purpose, but Python should be able to do a passable job. Your generator would create the test code; you would then vette the test code and need to maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

Your 5 columns and 6 filters example is simply a nested loop.

```
for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++)
{
    for (int filter = 0; filter < numberOfFilters; filter++)
    {
        RunTestForColumnFilterCombination(column, filter);
    }
}
```

To use all bit combinations in a range:

```
int getBit(int bits, int position)
{
    return ((bits >> position)  & 0x01);
}

for (int bits= 0; bits<= 7; bits++)
{
    RunTestForColumns(getBit(bits, 0), getBit(bits, 1), getBit(bits, 2));
}
```

Comment: No, I want to test with all possible combinations. If I have 3 columns, I want to test with column 1 active, column 1 & 2 active, column 1,2, & 3 active, column 2&3 active, and so on. Thank you for your answer though

Comment: Those are just bits.  For three columns, loop through the numbers zero through seven; each bit is a column "active" flag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey just a question. Does QA *must* code tests such like this? Aren't these test *unit tests*? If QA needs to code unit tests without specifications, something is going wrong in the development.

Comment: @Laiv: No.  It's just a way to create all of the combinations required.